# Hi i want to use border in my google map

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am making use of google map in my web page, i want to highlight the specific place with the border.can anyone help me by giving suggestions how to have border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a `Rectangle`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle) on the map; a tutorial is available in the [Rectangles section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Rectangles).